# Using conduits to build stock bar data off of a stream -- how do I get multiple depths?

Tags: haskell

Currently I have data that looks like this:

```
3-150
2-151
4-152
5-154
7-154
1-155
9-155
6-156
```

This is just artificial "tick" data, with the first representing the value of the tick and the second representing "seconds past midnight"

So for stock data, I need to sort this data into "bars". That is I need to group together all the bars for a given time.

An example would be 4 second bars. Ticks from 0-3 seconds past midnight would be 1 bar, 4-7 seconds past midnight would be another bar.

I have conduit/sink that looks like this that will compute 1 bar size:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

import Data.Conduit -- the core library
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL -- some list-like functions
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB -- bytes
import qualified Data.Conduit.Text as CT

data MyData = MyData Int Int
    deriving (Show)

binaryToData :: C.ByteString -> Maybe MyData
binaryToData bn = do
    let parts = C.split '-' bn
    case parts of
        (a:b:[]) -> MyData <$> (fst <$> (C.readInt a)) <*> (fst <$> (C.readInt b))
        _ -> Nothing

streamGenerator =
    CB.sourceFile "sample.txt" =$=
    CB.lines =$=
    CL.map binaryToData =$=
    CL.filter isJust =$=
    CL.map fromJust =$=
    CL.groupBy (\(MyData _ x) (MyData _ y) -> (x `quot` 4) == (y `quot` 4))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    mlines <- runResourceT $ streamGenerator $$ CL.consume
    print mlines
```

However I need multiple bar information off the stream at the same time. For example, for every 2 second bar I need a 4 second bar. If the 2 second bar being called is in the middle of the 4 second bar I want to output the previous 4 second bar.

Here is what I mean:

Standard Bars (numbers mean what ticks in terms of seconds past midnight the bar should contain):

```
2 second bar : 0-1, 2-3, 4-5, etc...
4 second bar : 0-3, 4-7, 8-11, etc...
combo: (0-1, null), (2-3, 0-3), (4-5, 0-3),  (6-7, 4-7), etc...
```

So instead of my current conduit of groupings of 2 and 4 second bars:

```
4 second bar : [[MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151],[MyData 4 152,MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155],[MyData 6 156]]
2 second bar : [[MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151],[MyData 4 152],[MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155],[MyData 6 156]]
```

I would like this conduit stream:

```
[([MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151], [MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151])
,([MyData 4 152], [MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151])
,([MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155], [MyData 4 152,MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155])
,([MyData 6 156],[MyData 4 152,MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155])]
```

But I can't seem to quite do it without doing some ugly stuff.

Comment: I'd look at `Data.Conduit.List.concatMapAccum` instead of `groupBy`, and `yield` a `Map` with each resolution you need... though I personally avoid doing much in the way of strategy development directly in a conduit, instead I like to use conduits to flow data in and out a strategy and rely on more specialized stream processors to handle the bulk of the computation, including bar generation if requested.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer your question using my `pipes` library, if you don't mind, since that's what I'm comfortable with.  You can translate this solution to `conduit` if you prefer.

The clean solution to this required pushback, but `pipes` does not yet have push back, so I went ahead and implemented it (and I will include as an extension library in the near future):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.State

-- Pushback primitives, soon to be in a `pipes` library

require :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => a' -> StateP [a] p a' a b' b m a
require a' = StateP $ \s -> runIdentityP $ do
    case s of
        [] -> do
            a <- request a'
            return (a, s)
        a:as -> do
            return (a, as)

pushback :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => a -> StateP [a] p a' a b' b m ()
pushback a = StateP $ \as -> runIdentityP $ return ((), a:as)

evalPushback = evalStateK []
```

With those in hand, the solution is straightforward:

```
data MyData = MyData Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Consumes ticks up until the deadline or the end of input
-- Returns the list of all ticks before the deadline
ticksUntil
 :: (Monad m, Proxy p)
 => Int -> () -> Consumer (StateP [Maybe MyData] p) (Maybe MyData) m [MyData]
ticksUntil deadline () = go where
    go = do
        x <- require ()
        case x of
            Just m@(MyData _ time) ->
                if (time < deadline)
                then do
                    ms <- go
                    return (m:ms)
                else do
                    pushback x
                    return []
            Nothing -> return []

bars
 :: (Monad m, Proxy p)
 => () -> Pipe (StateP [Maybe MyData] p) (Maybe MyData) ([MyData], [MyData]) m r
bars () = loop1 2 [] where
    -- First half of a 4-second window
    loop1 deadline b4 = do
        b2 <- (ticksUntil deadline >-> unitU) ()
        respond (b2, b4)
        loop2 (deadline + 2) b2 b4

    -- Second half of a 4-second window
    loop2 deadline b2 b4 = do
        b2' <- (ticksUntil deadline >-> unitU) ()
        let b4' = b2 ++ b2'
        respond (b2', b4')
        loop1 (deadline + 2) b4'

sample :: [MyData]
sample = [
    MyData 3 150,
    MyData 2 151,
    MyData 4 152,
    MyData 5 154,
    MyData 7 154,
    MyData 1 155,
    MyData 9 155,
    MyData 6 156]

-- Use the same trick as conduit: Nothing signals termination
source :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => () -> Producer p (Maybe MyData) m ()
source () = runIdentityP $ do
    (fromListS sample >-> mapD Just) ()
    respond Nothing

main = runProxy $
     source                 -- feed sample data
 >-> evalPushback bars      -- group the data into bars
 >-> filterD (/= ([], []))  -- Ignore empty bars
 >-> printD                 -- print outgoing bars
```

The magic is in the `bars` function.  It just switches between two states.  `loop1` is the first state where it is expecting the first bar of 2 values out of a set of 4, and the `loop2` is the second state where it is expecting the second bar of 2 values.

The hardest part of implementing this wasn't writing the code, but understanding your specification.  Fortunately, though, I think I figured out what you meant, because my code produces the exact same behavior as your test examples:

```
>>> main
([MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151],[MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151])
([MyData 4 152],[MyData 3 150,MyData 2 151])
([MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155],[MyData 4 152,MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155])
([MyData 6 156],[MyData 4 152,MyData 5 154,MyData 7 154,MyData 1 155,MyData 9 155])
```

If this interests you in `pipes`, then I recommend you check out the [`pipes` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), particularly the tutorial at [Control.Proxy.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html), which explains a lot of the idioms I use in the code.